# How to force CMake to link with debug libraries in a new Visual Studio configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'am using CMake to create a Visual Studio 2008 project. In this project I need to create a new configuration, called UnitaryTests. So, in CMakeLists.txt I put the line

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Release;Debug;UnitaryTest" CACHE STRING "Configurations" FORCE)
```

Later in the CMakeLists.txt file there is the following line:

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${ASTEK_LIBRARIES} )
```

to link with an external package. The variable ASTEK_LIBRARIES contains a text like:

```
debug;debug/libs;optimized;release/libs
```

My problem is that I must force the new configuration to only use the debug version of this package (currently it is using the release version). Do you know how to do this?

Note: it is not me that fill the variable ASTEK_LIBRARIES. It is created by a corporate script that I cannot change.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS "Debug;UnitaryTest")
```

If you also have `RelWithDebInfo` defined, this would belong in here too.

For further info run:

```
cmake --help-property DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

To force `target_link_libraries()` to link against a different library on a **per-target basis**, replace keywords as appropriate before linking. The following example shows how you would replace 'optimized' by 'general' to force a debug build to link against a release (optimized) library:

```
string(REPLACE "optimized" "general" MODIFIED_LIBS "${MY_LIBS}")
target_link_libraries(MyTarget ${MODIFIED_LIBS})
```

E.g. For MY_LIBS = "optimized;mylib.lib;debug;mylib_d.lib", MODIFIED_LIBS will be "general;mylib.lib;debug;mylib_d.lib". In this example, the 'general' keyword will cause both libraries to be linked against in your target during a debug build.

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html for more information.